# I want two ballons in mapview to open different activities. Is this possible?

Tags: android, google-maps

Question solved by @Niko. thanks =)

### look at the code below =) =)

Original Question: I can open just one activity from my ballons in the map. I want to open different activities depending in the ballon. 
Is it possible?

---

HelloItemizedOverlay.class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<MyOverlayItem>
{
    private static final String TAG = null;
    private ArrayList<MyOverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<MyOverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity activity;

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context)
    {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void addOverlay(MyOverlayItem overlayitem) 
    {
        mOverlays.add(overlayitem);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected MyOverlayItem createItem(int i)
    {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i)
    {
        // Intent Details = new Intent(mContext, Z_HH_flames.class);
        // mContext.startActivity(Details);
        Log.v(TAG, "inside onTap!!");
        Intent Details = new Intent(mContext, mOverlays.get(i).getActivityClassToOpen());
        mContext.startActivity(Details);

        /* OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();*/

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

mapView_HH.class:

```
public class MapView_HH extends MapActivity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        Drawable drawable;
        HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay;
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        MyOverlayItem overlayitem = new MyOverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!", New_activity_1.class);

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        //mapView.getOverlays().add((Overlay)itemizedoverlay);
        //mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(17385812,78480667);

        MyOverlayItem overlayitem2 = new MyOverlayItem(point2, "Namashkaar!", "I'm in Hyderabad, India!", New_activity_2.class);
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

MyOverlayItem.class:

```
public class MyOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {

    private final Class<?> activityClassToOpen;

    public MyOverlayItem (GeoPoint loc, String title, String snippet, Class<?> activityClassToOpen) {
        super(loc, title, snippet);
        this.activityClassToOpen = activityClassToOpen;
    }

    public Class<?> getActivityClassToOpen() {
        return activityClassToOpen;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes It is possible. Can you post your code here??

Comment: Hi @KrishnaSuthar I updated my question with my code

Comment: What is wrong here. Just pass the new activity class to the different balloons constructor and start that.

Answer (score 2):

Extend OverlayItem class and add the some information there which activity should be opened when it's clicked. Then in onTap, you get the item mOverlays.get(index).getActivityClassToOpen() and use that for the intent.

```
public class MyOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {

private final Class<?> activityClassToOpen;

public MyOverlayItem (GeoPoint loc, String title, String snippet, Class<?> activityClassToOpen) {
    super(loc, title, snippet);
    this.activityClassToOpen = activityClassToOpen;
}

public Class<?> getActivityClassToOpen() {
    return activityClassToOpen;
}
}
```

onTap function:

```
Intent Details = new Intent(mContext, mOverlays.get(i).getActivityClassToOpen());
```

Comment: can't think of any, but that's pretty straight forward and easy solution to implement.

Comment: I posted the example of OverlayItem class you could use, then just change your mOverlays array to store MyOverlayItem type objects and when creating object pass the activity class for the overlayitem.

Comment: Can you tell me where you are still struggling ? Have you changed the private ArrayList<MyOverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<MyOverlayItem>(); and addOverlay(MyOverlayItem overlay)

Comment: Yes I did. I get an error with MabObject. Where do I declare the new Activies? do I declare them where I declare the coordinates?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10259/discussion-between-niko-and-andrew-d)